# The change of error according to the k-value change

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

When I was studying about K-fold I was wondering about CV-error.
With a higher number of folds, the estimated cross- validation error will be higher or smaller or no change (on Average)?

I think the CV-error will go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between CV-error and the number of folds isn't about one entity goes up and the other goes down, it's somehow arbitrary. We need to choose K in a way to give us the best estimation for the CV-error. Choosing larger K means less bias towards overestimating the true expected error but the variance will be high.

To answer the main question the relation between K and CV-error depends on alot of factors mainly the distribution of the data, the size of the data and the true performance of the model.

Comment: So if you're choosing among "highher", "lower", "same", "can't tell", you're saying can't tell is the answer?

Comment: Using more folds than needed will overfit the data which will make CV-error as low as possible but this number doesn't  represent the real performance of the model. what I'm saying is "higher" folds means "lower" CV-error but "can't tell" about the real performance.